# Compute a polynomial via a product using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, polynomial-math

I started learning `Python` and I have been referring to "A primer on Scientific Programming with Python by HP Langtangen". I just started the topic on functions and I have been assigned a task to develop a function which computes a polynomial by product. The exact question being

Given n+1 roots r0, r1, . . . , rn of a polynomial p(x) of degree n+1, p(x)
can be computed by

```
p(x) = (x - r0)(x - r1) · · · (x - rn-1)(x - rn)
```

Write a function poly(x, roots) that takes x and a list roots of the
roots as arguments and returns p(x)

Is there any way this problem can be solved without using `Sympy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate.

```
def poly(x, roots):
    poly = 1
    for r in roots:
        poly *= (x - r)

    return poly

# EXAMPLE
x = 1
roots = [2, 5, 7]
print ( poly(x, roots) )
```

Comment: Thank you mtk99 for your input. But it would evaluate the function at x = 1. The desired output is the polynomial equation, which according to input has to be (x-2)(x-5)(x-7).

Comment: The last line was just and example! What you are asking was just the function poly(x, roots)

Comment: Oh yeah. I do understand that the last line was an example. But when I run the function as poly(x,[2,5,7]), it gives me 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'int'

Comment: You must be doing something wrong.. Could you post your code?

Comment: roots = [-1,1,2]

    def poly(roots,x):
        p = 1
        for i in range(len(roots)):
            p = p*(x - roots[i])
        return p

    print(poly(roots,3))

Comment: Sorry, but that works on my side with no error. There is still a logic problem. Keep in mind that if there are no roots, you probably want to return 0 but your code returns 1

Comment: thanks @mtk99. I will check my code logic once again to see where I am going wrong Thanks for all the help

Comment: If there are no roots, returning the constant function 1 is rather logical. Returning the constant 0 gives a function with infinitely many zeros, for an input that prescribes no roots at all.